# Naive-bayes multinomial text classifier using Data frame in Scala Spark

Tags: apache-spark, text-classification, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I am trying to build a NaiveBayes classifier, loading the data from database as DataFrame which contains (label, text).
Here's the sample of data (multinomial label):

```
label|             feature|
+-----+--------------------+
|    1|combusting prepar...|
|    1|adhesives for ind...|
|    1|                    |
|    1| salt for preserving|
|    1|auxiliary fluids ...|
```

I have used following transformation for tokenization, stopword, n-gram, and hashTF :

```scala
val selectedData = df.select("label", "feature")
// Tokenize RDD
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("feature").setOutputCol("words")
val regexTokenizer = new   RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("feature").setOutputCol("words").setPattern("\\W")
val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(selectedData)
tokenized.select("words", "label").take(3).foreach(println)

// Removing stop words
val remover = new        StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("filtered")
val parsedData = remover.transform(tokenized) 

// N-gram
val ngram = new NGram().setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("ngrams")
val ngramDataFrame = ngram.transform(parsedData) 
ngramDataFrame.take(3).map(_.getAs[Stream[String]]("ngrams").toList).foreach(println)

//hashing function
val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("ngrams").setOutputCol("hash").setNumFeatures(1000)
val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(ngramDataFrame)
```

Output of the transformation:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------    --------------+--------------------+
|label|             feature|               words|            filtered|                  ngrams|                hash|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------    --------------+--------------------+
|    1|combusting prepar...|[combusting, prep...|[combusting, prep...|    [combusting prepa...|(1000,[124,161,69...|
|    1|adhesives for ind...|[adhesives, for, ...|[adhesives, indus...| [adhesives indust...|(1000,[451,604],[...|
|    1|                    |                  []|                  []|                     []|        (1000,[],[])|
|    1| salt for preserving|[salt, for, prese...|  [salt, preserving]|   [salt   preserving]|  (1000,[675],[1.0])|
|    1|auxiliary fluids ...|[auxiliary, fluid...|[auxiliary, fluid...|[auxiliary fluids...|(1000,[661,696,89...|
```

To build a Naive Bayes model, I need to convert the label and feature into `LabelPoint`. Following approaches I have tried to convert a dataframe into RDD and create labelpoint:

```scala
val rddData = featurizedData.select("label","hash").rdd

val trainData = rddData.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0), parts(1))
}


val rddData = featurizedData.select("label","hash").rdd.map(r =>   (Try(r(0).asInstanceOf[Integer]).get.toDouble,   Try(r(1).asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector]).get))

val trainData = rddData.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble,   Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 scala> val trainData = rddData.map { line =>
 |   val parts = line.split(',')
 |   LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
 | }
 <console>:67: error: value split is not a member of (Double,    org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector)
     val parts = line.split(',')
                      ^
<console>:68: error: not found: value Vectors
     LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble,   Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
```

---

Edit 1:

As per below suggestion, I have created the LabelPoint and train the Model.

```
val trainData = featurizedData.select("label","features")

val trainLabel = trainData.map(line =>  LabeledPoint(Try(line(0).asInstanceOf[Integer]).get.toDouble,Try(line(1).asInsta nceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector]).get))

val splits = trainLabel.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)

val model = NaiveBayes.train(training, lambda = 1.0, modelType = "multinomial")

val predictionAndLabels = test.map { point => 
   val score = model.predict(point.features)
   (score, point.label)}
```

I am getting less accuracy around 40% with N-gram and without N-gram along with different hash feature number. My dataset contains 5000 row and 45 mutlinomial label. Is there any way to improve the model performance? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to transform your `featurizedData` into an `RDD`, because `Apache Spark` has two libraries `ML` and `MLLib`, the first one works with `DataFrame`s, whereas `MLLib` works using  `RDD`s. Therefore, you can work with `ML` because you already have a `DataFrame`.

In order to achieve this, you just need to rename your columns to (`label`, `features`), and fit your model, as they show in [NaiveBayes](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=naivebayes#pyspark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes), example bellow.

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0])),
    Row(label=0.0, features=Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0])),
    Row(label=1.0, features=Vectors.dense([1.0, 0.0]))])
nb = NaiveBayes(smoothing=1.0, modelType="multinomial")
model = nb.fit(df)
```

About the **error** you get, is because you already have a `SparseVector`, and that class doesn't have a `split` method. So thinking more about this, your `RDD`  almost has the structure you actually require, but you have to convert the `Tuple` to a `LabeledPoint`.

There are some techniques to improve the performance, the first one that comes to my mind is to remove stopwords (e.g. the, a, an, to, although, etc...), the second one is to count the number of different words in your texts and then construct the vectors manually, i.e. this is because if the hashing number is low then different words might have the same hash, hence a bad performance.

Comment: Thanks @alberto for reply. Pls correct me if I am wrong, I am trying to featurizedData to transform data into LabelPoint. Can you suggest me any method to convert the data into LabelPoint.

Comment: @ManishV Read the last part of my message, I give you a hint over there :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @alberto, I have updated the code and created the model. Can you suggest me to improve the performance of the model.