# Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Given my pyspark Row object:

```py
>>> row
Row(clicked=0, features=SparseVector(7, {0: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 6: 0.752}))
>>> row.clicked
0
>>> row.features
SparseVector(7, {0: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 6: 0.752})
>>> type(row.features)
<class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'>
```

However, row.features failed to pass isinstance(row.features,Vector) test.

```py
>>> isinstance(SparseVector(7, {0: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 6: 0.752}), Vector)
True
>>> isinstance(row.features, Vector)
False
>>> isinstance(deepcopy(row.features), Vector)
False
```

This strange error made me in huge trouble. Without passing "isinstance(row.features, Vector)," I am not able to generate LabeledPoint using map function.
I will be really grateful if anyone can solve this problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is is unlikely an error. You didn't provide a [code required to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but most likely you use Spark 2.0 with ML transformers and you compare wrong entities.

Let's illustrate that with an example. Simple data

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder

row = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="x", outputCol="features").transform(
    sc.parallelize([(1.0, )]).toDF(["x"])
).first()
```

Now lets import different vector classes:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vector as MLVector, Vectors as MLVectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vector as MLLibVector, Vectors as MLLibVectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import  LabeledPoint
```

and make tests:

```py
isinstance(row.features, MLLibVector)
```

```
False
```

```py
isinstance(row.features, MLVector)
```

```
True
```

As you see what we have is `pyspark.ml.linalg.Vector` not `pyspark.mllib.linalg.Vector` which is not compatible with the old API:

```py
LabeledPoint(0.0, row.features)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector
```

You could convert ML object to MLLib one:

```py
from pyspark.ml import linalg as ml_linalg

def as_mllib(v):
    if isinstance(v, ml_linalg.SparseVector):
        return MLLibVectors.sparse(v.size, v.indices, v.values)
    elif isinstance(v, ml_linalg.DenseVector):
        return MLLibVectors.dense(v.toArray())
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unsupported type: {0}".format(type(v)))

LabeledPoint(0, as_mllib(row.features))
```

```
LabeledPoint(0.0, (1,[],[]))
```

or simply:

```py
LabeledPoint(0, MLLibVectors.fromML(row.features))
```

```
LabeledPoint(0.0, (1,[],[]))
```

but generally speaking you should avoid situations when it is necessary.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to convert the SparseVectors from pyspark.ml to pyspark.mllib SparseVectors you could use MLUtils.
Say **df** is your dataframe and the column with the SparseVectors is named "features". Then the following few lines let you accomplish this:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
df = MLUtils.convertVectorColumnsFromML(df, "features")
```

This problem occured for me, because when using CountVectorizer from pyspark.ml.feature I could not create LabeledPoints, because of the incompatibility with SparseVector from pyspark.ml

I wonder why their latest documentation [CountVectorizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#CountVectorizer) does not use the "new" SparseVector class. As the classification algorithms need LabeledPoints this makes no sense to me...

**UPDATE**:
I misunderstood that the ml library is designed for DataFrame-Objects and the mllib library is for RDD-objects.
The DataFrame-Datastructure is recommended since Spark > 2,0, because SparkSession is more compatible than the SparkContext (but stores an SparkContext-object) and does deliver DataFrame instead of RDD's.
I found this post that got me the "aha"-effect: [mllib and ml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856042/naive-bayes-multinomial-text-classifier-using-data-frame-in-scala-spark). Thanks Alberto Bonsanto :).

To use f.e. NaiveBayes from mllib, I had to transform my DataFrame into a LabeledPoint-objects for NaiveBayes from mllib.

But it is way easier to use NaiveBayes from ml because you don't need LabeledPoints but can just specify the feature- and class-col for your dataframe.

PS: I was struggling with this problems for hours, so I felt that I need to post it here :)

Comment: `pyspark` feels like a good example of how _not_ to do an api, tbh -- somehow both unintuitive _and_ unstable. Usually it's unintuitive but at least stable as fixing is seen as not worth it. Or unstable but at least intuitive because the fixes are making it thus. I suppose it has the disadvantage of being a second-class citizen behind `java` implementation so it's left holding the language-translation-bag.