# PySpark: Converting features to Labeled point for SVMwithSGD

Tags: pyspark, libsvm

I have a df like this -

```
+-----+--------------------+
|label|            features|
+-----+--------------------+
|    1|(262144,[6693,118...|
|    0|(262144,[25607,25...|
|    0|(262144,[13652,21...|
|    0|(262144,[33751,59...|
|    0|(262144,[10675,39...|
|    0|(262144,[88597,14...|
|    0|(262144,[75042,11...|
|    0|(262144,[4009,240...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

I want to train it with using SVMwithSGD. I tried to train using the above df but got this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SVMwithSVDcode.py", line 76, in <module>
    svm = SVMWithSGD.train(df)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 553, in train
    return _regression_train_wrapper(train, SVMModel, data, initialWeights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 210, in _regression_train_wrapper
    raise TypeError("data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got %s" % type(first))
TypeError: data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
```

According to Spark documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-support-vector-machines-svms SVM requires df in form of Labeled point.

So, I tried like this -

```
labeled_point_df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))
svm = SVMwithSVG(labeled_point_df)
```

But after using above code I got following error -

```
18/02/21 10:38:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "SVMwithSVDcode.py", line 75, in <lambda>
    labeled_point = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 83, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/02/21 10:38:40 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "SVMwithSVDcode.py", line 75, in <lambda>
    labeled_point = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 83, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/02/21 10:38:40 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SVMwithSVDcode.py", line 76, in <module>
    svm = SVMWithSGD.train(labeled_point)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 553, in train
    return _regression_train_wrapper(train, SVMModel, data, initialWeights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 208, in _regression_train_wrapper
    first = data.first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1361, in first
    rs = self.take(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1343, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 992, in runJob
    port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "SVMwithSVDcode.py", line 75, in <lambda>
    labeled_point = (selected.select(col("toxic"), col("features")).rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.toxic, row.features)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 83, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "SVMwithSVDcode.py", line 75, in <lambda>
    labeled_point = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 83, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: which spark version you are using ?? and  it's 'svm = SVMwithSGD.train(labeled_point_df) ' , correct ??

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074182/cannot-convert-type-class-pyspark-ml-linalg-sparsevector-into-vector

Comment: If you are using mllib, import Vector from pyspark.mllib.linalg and not pyspark.ml.linalg